# Error stating missing tokenizer when running zero shot model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

This example was taken from hugging face but yields a model loading error. I thought I downloaded this model, but is anywhere aware of how i might be able to do so to avoid this error? Thanks, Will

```
from ktrain import text 
zsl = text.ZeroShotClassifier()
topic_strings=['politics', 'elections', 'sports', 'films', 'television']
doc = 'I am extremely dissatisfied with the President and will definitely vote in 2020.'
zsl.predict(doc, topic_strings=topic_strings, include_labels=True)
```

results in:

OSError: Model name 'facebook/bart-large-mnli' was not found in tokenizers model name list (bart-large, bart-large-mnli, bart-large-cnn, bart-large-xsum). We assumed 'facebook/bart-large-mnli' was a path, a model identifier, or url to a directory containing vocabulary files named ['vocab.json', 'merges.txt'] but couldn't find such vocabulary files at this path or url.

Answer (score 1):

derp I did not have the default model on hand so i changed line 2 to point to a model i was properly able to load:

```
zsl = text.ZeroShotClassifier(model_name='bart-large-mnli')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a version of `transformers` that is older than 2.11.  As of 2.11 `transformers`, BART (and some other models) must be specified with full model ID as indicated in the CHANGELOG of `transformers` 2.11:

```
URLs to model weights are not hardcoded anymore (@julien-c)
Archive maps were dictionaries linking pre-trained models to their S3 URLs. Since the arrival of the model hub, these have become obsolete.

⚠️ This PR is breaking for the following models: BART, Flaubert, bert-japanese, bert-base-finnish, bert-base-dutch. ⚠️
Those models now have to be instantiated with their full model id:

"cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese"
"cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-whole-word-masking"
"cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char"
"cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-whole-word-masking"
"TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1"
"TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1"
"wietsedv/bert-base-dutch-cased"
"flaubert/flaubert_small_cased"
"flaubert/flaubert_base_uncased"
"flaubert/flaubert_base_cased"
"flaubert/flaubert_large_cased"

all variants of "facebook/bart"
```